# Sourcing functions properly from .R files in parallel processing

Tags: r, import, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

I'm trying to find a way to properly source .R files to use the functions in a foreach loop that runs in parallel. The solution I put below only works if the folder containing the functions is in the current directory and I want to avoid it. The file containing the function below and all the files sourced below are in the same directory called "R".
I guess there are cleaner ways to do this, but I can't find them. Thank you for your help.

```
RESULT <- foreach(o=1:mi, .inorder = FALSE, .combine = "rbind", .packages = c("mlogit", "dfidx", "plyr", "dplyr"), .options.snow = opts) %dopar% {
  
  if (ParParams){
    source("R/SI3_SpecificModelImputation.R")
    source("R/SI4_InitialNAsImpute.R")
    source("R/SI5_TerminalNasImpute.R")
    source("R/SI6_SLGNAsImpute.R")
    source("R/SICommon.R")
```

Comment: I suggest you create a package, but if you don't want to just source before entering the loop

Comment: You can just put the full path to the R scripts, then it doesn't matter where the code is run from. Like `source(paste0(rest_of_path,"R/SI..."))`